# Loop through all cookies and add a class depending on true or false

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I have a series of items with individual ID's on a couple of different pages, so far I'm able to create the cookie and update it to true or false depending on if the class has been added, although the class being added does not persist through page refreshes. I've been using my google fu as much as possible but I cannot find another example of how to do this. I need to check on page load if the cookie exists and if so apply the class to this individual element, of which there are a dozen or so.

So far I've gotten here:

```
<script>

  setCookie = (cName, cValue, expDays) => {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (expDays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    var expires = "expires="+ date.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cName + "=" + cValue + ";" + expires + "; path=/";
  }

   getCookie = (cName) => {
    const name = cName + "=";
    const cDecoded = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    const cArr = cDecoded.split("; ");
    var value;
    cArr.forEach((val) => {
       if (val.indexOf(name) === 0) value = val.substring(name.length);
     });
    return value;
  };

  $('.accomo-fav').on('click', function() {
    var likeVal = $(this).attr('id')
    if ($(this).hasClass('active-fav')) {
      setCookie(likeVal, false, 90)
      $(this).removeClass('active-fav') 
    } else {
      $(this).addClass('active-fav')
      setCookie(likeVal, true, 90)
    }
  })
    
</script>
```

And this is a shortened part of the individual block I'm using as a container:

```
<div class="room-row-container">
            <div class="lg:w-1/2 w-full relative search-image">
                <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>" alt="Thumbnail Image" class="absolute object-cover w-full h-full">
            </div>
            <div class="lg:w-1/2 w-full relative lg:p-8">
                <div class="w-full flex flex-row items-center justify-between mb-8">
                    <h4 class="text-3xl mb-2"><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
                    <svg class="accomo-fav" id="<?php the_ID(); ?>" width="22" height="21" viewBox="0 0 22 21" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                        <path d="M15.5 1C13.76 1 12.09 1.81 11 3.09C9.91 1.81 8.24 1 6.5 1C3.42 1 1 3.42 1 6.5C1 10.28 4.4 13.36 9.55 18.04L11 19.35L12.45 18.03C17.6 13.36 21 10.28 21 6.5C21 3.42 18.58 1 15.5 1Z" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                        <path d="M15.5 1C13.76 1 12.09 1.81 11 3.09C9.91 1.81 8.24 1 6.5 1C3.42 1 1 3.42 1 6.5C1 10.28 4.4 13.36 9.55 18.04L11 19.35L12.45 18.03C17.6 13.36 21 10.28 21 6.5C21 3.42 18.58 1 15.5 1Z" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                    </svg>
                </div>              
            </div>
        </div>
```

My thinking is that it needs to loop through each of the room-row-container blocks and then check is they exist, or the ID's of the cookies if they have been created. In all honesty feel a bit lost on this!

**Solution**

After reading the comments and rebuilding the script, I started using localStorage and managed to come up with a simple script that allowed me to set and remove Items based on a click.

```
  $('.accomo-fav').on('click', function() {
    var item = $(this).attr('id');
    if ($(this).hasClass('active-fav')) {
      $(this).removeClass('active-fav')
      localStorage.removeItem(item)
    } else {
      localStorage.setItem(item, true)
      $(this).addClass('active-fav')
    }
  })
  
  var arrayOfKeys = Object.keys(localStorage);

  console.log(arrayOfKeys)

  arrayOfKeys.map( function(key) {
    console.log(key)
    $('.accomo-fav[data-like="' + key + '"]').addClass('active-fav')
  })
```

Comment: Are you sure that Cookies are the way to go here ? It looks like you might be better off using html 5 [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Comment: Yeah it needs to last longer than a singular session as it's for a hotel and the client may come back later to see which one they liked

Comment: The Localstorage lasts until you delete it. So it will still be there once you come back.

Comment: Ahh yeah thankyou my error, I actually went back and rebuilt the block using localStorage - I've added my solution to the post.